# Find model with part of title using ElasticSearch / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

There is the following Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    def self.search query
      __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: query,
                        fields: ['title']
                }
            },
                filter: { 
                    and: [
                        { term: { deleted: false } },
                        { term: { enabled: true } }
                    ]
                }
        }
      )
    end

    settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
      mappings dynamic: 'false' do
        indexes :title, analyzer: 'english'
      end
    end
end

Post.import
```

I have one Post with 'Amsterdam' title. When I execute Post.search('Amsterdam') I will get one record, all is good. But if I execute Post.search('Amster') I will get no records. What do I wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks!

OS - OS X, ElasticSearch I installed using Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use *nGram tokenizer*, in order to create a partial text search. A very good example of how to do this can be found [here.](http://mnylen.tumblr.com/post/22963609412/elasticsearch-and-a-simple-contains-search) That said, I would be very careful with nGram, as it can often turn up unrelated results.

This is because the substring "mon" is contained within all of the strings: "monkey", "money", and "monday". All of which are unrelated.

**Alternatively (What I would do.)**

You could try making it a *fuzzy* search. However, the max distance with fuzzy search is only two, which still doesn't return anything in your example. However, it tends to return relevant results.

The example I found: [How to use Fuzzy Search](https://www.found.no/foundation/fuzzy-search/)

```
# Perform a fuzzy search!
POST /fuzzy_products/product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "Vacuummm",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```